# Causal inference, stratification to mitigate confounders in continuous variables?

Tags: causality, continuous-data, discrete-data, confounding, stratification

Handling confounders in continuous variables

In Statistical Rethinking, the author shows that in different situations, a confounder (fork, pipe, collider, descendent) will induce spurious correlations. For the collider, he shows that if Z is Bernoulli variable dependent on both X and Y, X and Y could appear uncorrelated. However, if you condition on Z=0, the correlation looks much stronger and likewise for Z=1.

How does this stratification work for continuous variables? Say that Z was normally distributed (but still dependent on X and Y), conditioning on 0, 1, or any specific value doesn't make sense.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpP-_mBvECI&list=PLDcUM9US4XdMROZ57-OIRtIK0aOynbgZN&index=7 (45:28)

Comment: You can "condition" on a variable in a number of ways. In a linear regression setting, conditioning can be as simple as including that variable on the right-hand side.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, what would 'on the right-hand side' mean in context? I'm picturing anything in the ... in $y$ ~ ... (predictor variables.)

Comment: Yes, exactly. The "right-hand side" means the predictors.

Answer (score 0):

**First**:
I have not watched the video, so I don't know what definitions  are used there, but in the books and papers I have read:

- A confounder is only a fork, not a collider.
- An unobserved collider is completely blocking the path between $X$ and $Y$, it is not just making it "appear" to be uncorrelated. This is [d-separation](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/d-sep.html). So if there is no other path between $X$ and $Y$, those two are independent.

**Your question**:
IIUC, your point is that, for a given dataset, "conditioning a continuous variable $Z$ on e.g. 1" would refer to reducing the dataset to those observations which contain $1$ in the column for $Z$ (stratification), and since the probability of a continuous variable to have a single value is zero, this will not return any observations given sufficient resolution (or it would return only one observation if you chose to condition on a value that appears in your data). That is correct and in this case you cannot really do conditioning in this way.

What you can do, is to **partially** condition on the collider $Z$, e.g. by conditioning on a discrete child $D$ of $Z$. This $D$ could be e.g. a binary variable describing whether $Z$ is inside some interval or not. This partial conditioning would result in "partial opening" of the connection between $X$ and $Y$. The larger this interval gets, the less conditioning you have.